# Combine multiple rows to a single cell for a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
  day V1 V9 V13 V14 V15 V16
1    1  2  3   0   0   0   0
2    1  5  3   L   L   0   0
3    1  5  1   S   L   L   0
4    1  4  3   S   0   0   0
5    1  5  2   S   L   L   0
6    1  5  1   S   M   L   0
7    1  4  1   L   L   0   0
8    1  4  1   M   S   0   0
9    1  1  3   0   0   0   0
10   1  4  1   S   L   0   0
11   2  1  3   0   0   0   0
12   2  2  1   0   0   0   0
13   2  3  3   0   0   0   0
14   2  1  3   0   0   0   0
15   2  1  1   0   0   0   0
16   2  4  3   S   0   0   0
17   2  4  3   S   0   0   0
18   2  3  3   0   0   0   0
19   2  3  1   S   0   0   0
20   2  4  1   L   M   0   0
```

I need to convert it to look something like this

```
 day V1 V9 V13 V14 V15 V16
1    1  2  3   0   0   0   0
2       5  3   L   L   0   0
3       5  1   S   L   L   0
4       4  3   S   0   0   0
5       5  2   S   L   L   0
6       5  1   S   M   L   0
7       4  1   L   L   0   0
8       4  1   M   S   0   0
9       1  3   0   0   0   0
10      4  1   S   L   0   0
11   2  1  3   0   0   0   0
12      2  1   0   0   0   0
13      3  3   0   0   0   0
14      1  3   0   0   0   0
15      1  1   0   0   0   0
16      4  3   S   0   0   0
17      4  3   S   0   0   0
18      3  3   0   0   0   0
19      3  1   S   0   0   0
20      4  1   L   M   0   0
```

This is similar to working on the excel merge command for multiple rows of a specific column. I could not figure it out 
Maybe I can keep the day value in the middle for a better representation. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should consider editing your question to "Removing repeated values from Vector?"

Comment: This is a generated data frame and the repeated values will be there as they represent some categories (levels)

Comment: Please upvote and accept my solution if it does what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `duplicated` to replace repeated values in `day` column with empty values.

```
df$day[duplicated(df$day)] <- ''
df

#   day V1 V9 V13 V14 V15 V16
#1    1  2  3   0   0   0   0
#2       5  3   L   L   0   0
#3       5  1   S   L   L   0
#4       4  3   S   0   0   0
#5       5  2   S   L   L   0
#6       5  1   S   M   L   0
#7       4  1   L   L   0   0
#8       4  1   M   S   0   0
#9       1  3   0   0   0   0
#10      4  1   S   L   0   0
#11   2  1  3   0   0   0   0
#12      2  1   0   0   0   0
#13      3  3   0   0   0   0
#14      1  3   0   0   0   0
#15      1  1   0   0   0   0
#16      4  3   S   0   0   0
#17      4  3   S   0   0   0
#18      3  3   0   0   0   0
#19      3  1   S   0   0   0
#20      4  1   L   M   0   0
```

This converts `day` column to character, probably safer to replace with `NA` instead.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V1 = c(2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L
), V9 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), V13 = c("0", "L", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "L", "M", "0", "S", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "S", "S", "0", 
"S", "L"), V14 = c("0", "L", "L", "0", "L", "M", "L", "S", "0", 
"L", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "M"), V15 = c("0", 
"0", "L", "0", "L", "L", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), V16 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
Data <- tribble(~"day",~"V1",~"V9",~"V13",~"V14",~"V15",~"V16",
                "1","2","3","0","0","0","0",
                "1","5","3","L","L","0","0",
                "1","5","1","S","L","L","0",
                "1","4","3","S","0","0","0",
                "1","5","2","S","L","L","0",
                "1","5","1","S","M","L","0",
                "1","4","1","L","L","0","0",
                "1","4","1","M","S","0","0",
                "1","1","3","0","0","0","0",
                "1","4","1","S","L","0","0",
                "2","1","3","0","0","0","0",
                "2","2","1","0","0","0","0",
                "2","3","3","0","0","0","0",
                "2","1","3","0","0","0","0",
                "2","1","1","0","0","0","0",
                "2","4","3","S","0","0","0",
                "2","4","3","S","0","0","0",
                "2","3","3","0","0","0","0",
                "2","3","1","S","0","0","0",
                "2","4","1","L","M","0","0")
Data %>%
  group_split(day) %>%
  map_df(~ .x %>%
        mutate(day = c(unique(day), rep("",n()-1)))
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 20 x 7
   day   V1    V9    V13   V14   V15   V16  
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 "1"   2     3     0     0     0     0    
 2 ""    5     3     L     L     0     0    
 3 ""    5     1     S     L     L     0    
 4 ""    4     3     S     0     0     0    
 5 ""    5     2     S     L     L     0    
 6 ""    5     1     S     M     L     0    
 7 ""    4     1     L     L     0     0    
 8 ""    4     1     M     S     0     0    
 9 ""    1     3     0     0     0     0    
10 ""    4     1     S     L     0     0    
11 "2"   1     3     0     0     0     0    
12 ""    2     1     0     0     0     0    
13 ""    3     3     0     0     0     0    
14 ""    1     3     0     0     0     0    
15 ""    1     1     0     0     0     0    
16 ""    4     3     S     0     0     0    
17 ""    4     3     S     0     0     0    
18 ""    3     3     0     0     0     0    
19 ""    3     1     S     0     0     0    
20 ""    4     1     L     M     0     0
```

Comment: This is not working as my data is a data frame. Can you recheck and is there any solution available with R inbuilt command?

Comment: My solution works with the package ```tidyverse```. Use ```install.packages("tidyverse")```.

Comment: I installed and tried that buddy. Still it is showing error

Comment: Error: Column `day` is unknown

Comment: I've added the output I get here. I do not see such an error. Try copying my exact code into your IDE and running it.

Comment: I think you have used tribble and for me it is dataframe

Comment: I feel that it makes no difference as far as the work is concerned. Please use whichever solution is preferable to you!

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows to change is known in advance, this works:

```
Data$day[c(2:10,12:20)] <- ""
```

If the number of rows to be changed is unknown, this works:

```
Data$day[which(Data$day=="1")[-1]] <- ""
Data$day[which(Data$day=="2")[-1]] <- ""
```

Result:

```
Data
# A tibble: 20 x 7
   day   V1    V9    V13   V14   V15   V16  
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 "1"   2     3     0     0     0     0    
 2 ""    5     3     L     L     0     0    
 3 ""    5     1     S     L     L     0    
 4 ""    4     3     S     0     0     0    
 5 ""    5     2     S     L     L     0    
 6 ""    5     1     S     M     L     0    
 7 ""    4     1     L     L     0     0    
 8 ""    4     1     M     S     0     0    
 9 ""    1     3     0     0     0     0    
10 ""    4     1     S     L     0     0    
11 "2"   1     3     0     0     0     0    
12 ""    2     1     0     0     0     0    
13 ""    3     3     0     0     0     0    
14 ""    1     3     0     0     0     0    
15 ""    1     1     0     0     0     0    
16 ""    4     3     S     0     0     0    
17 ""    4     3     S     0     0     0    
18 ""    3     3     0     0     0     0    
19 ""    3     1     S     0     0     0    
20 ""    4     1     L     M     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(day = replace(day, duplicated(day), ''))
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I need to combine rows of the column to represent all 10 rows . I mean after converting it to a single cell, is it possible the single row can show 10 rows simultaneously. Something similar to a table .

Comment: Something similar to the multirow table is what I require. A single row will represent multiple row values of other columns.

Answer (score -1):

Base R Solution:

```
df$day <- with(df, ifelse(c(1, diff(day)) == 0, NA_integer_, day))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(day = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V1 = c(2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L
), V9 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), V13 = c("0", "L", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "L", "M", "0", "S", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "S", "S", "0", 
"S", "L"), V14 = c("0", "L", "L", "0", "L", "M", "L", "S", "0", 
"L", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "M"), V15 = c("0", 
"0", "L", "0", "L", "L", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), V16 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```